# Load image for HTML img element from JSON property while URL not directly accessible

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, json, wikitude

OK, this one is rather complicated to explain, which explains the verbose title:
In my Objective C application I generate a JSON string to hold all of my properties for the objects I need to draw in the ARchitect browser of the wikitude SDK (as far as I know the Wikitude SDK only handles JSON) via:

```
NSString *javaScript = [self convertPoiModelToJson:self.poiData.pois];
NSString *javaScriptToCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"newData('%@')", javaScript];
```

One particular object I am interested in is stored as a string in that JSON string, it's the URL to an image. However, this image is behind a password protected area on our webserver and the app handles the authentication.

The problems start when I am in the ARchitect Browser, which is basically a .html file with calls to specific wikitude javascript functions to build the augmented reality world and show it in a UIWebView in the app. I want to show that image when a POI in the augmented view is clicked in the footer popup which is a basic html div container. So now I have a URL to an image resource on the webserver, which I cannot directly access with

```
document.getElementById("thumb").src = jsonObject.thumbUrl;
```

because of the authentication needed and the only way I was successful to load that image was via the `var poiImage = new AR.ImageResource(jsonObject[i].iconURL, {onError: errorLoadingImage});` method but then I can only display it in the augmented view but not in the footer.

I tried it with providing a static string from some other image in the web or to local resources to the img element in the footer section in the view without problems like that: `document.getElementById("thumb").src="marker.png";` and it works fine, also the image is correctly loaded in the augmented view.

I have read about encoding the image (which I can access and download in the objective c part of the app) in base64 and storing that string in an additional JSON property to load it into the src property of the html img element with a `<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE&$_ENCODED_DATA"></img>` but this seems like a really dirty and overly impractical workaround/hack for what I try to accomplish. Also I don't know if it's a better idea to start reading about how to implement the authentication to access that image in the protected area of the webserver or rather begin implementing the ugly base64 encoding or continue searching for alternatives.

I'm not asking for a solution but rather for suggestions what possibilities I have left to access that image. Since I ran out of ideas, any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Short summary:

- image accessible and downloaded in objective c part
- image is accessible with the AR.ImageResource method of the wikitude SDK (but not needed)
- image cannot be accessed directly via the url from javascript because authentication is needed

(I hope my question is comprehensible, feel free to ask If something is unclear, especially since English is not my first language and it would be even complicated to explain that in German..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the image in Objective-C / Cocoa, store it locally on your iOS device and pass the local path of the image via JSON into your Architect World?

You can then load the local image with your `AR.ImageResouce` and your div container.

Comment: that's what I finally did since it was the easiest and most forward approach without providing a public place on the webserver to store the images or authenticate again or use dirty binary stream hacks or even load the image again..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's think a bit about this, as it seems like a good mess.

If I'm understanding well your problem, all is about your javascript code needing to reach a url where an image is located, being unable to do so because that place requires some sort of validation to access.

In this scenario I'd look for moving images to a place out of the restricted site. Maybe trying to save them from the objective-C part into one *public* place that's reachable by javascript. This may be tricky as the I/O operation could slow your code execution... Of course you'll always have the option to move those images just outside of the *restricted* area but I supose that's not feasible as you could suposed that solution by yourself.

Other way... if your environment configuration allows it (I fear there isn't enough info about it on the question) is to try to execute your javascript part (I wonder if it's enclosed into a webpage executed from a webserver) with a user with permissions into the *restricted* area. This, of course, could be totally a no-no depending on what your javascript part does and why your *restricted* area is protected by validation.

If you don't want to move out the files, copy them temporarily gives performance problems and errors, and user impersonation through the javascript executing user is not an option I fear your unique alternative is to efectively try to pass a binary stream of data with the image through the JSON string... dirty...

Comment: you wondering if the javascript part is on a webpage on a webserver gave me the idea to put it on our server within the restricted area to allow access to the images, since right now it's just in a static html file..will keep you updated

Comment: Probably your users will need to use user/password to reach the html file on the server, unless you enable anonymous access to it or your users are already logged onto the restricted area.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wikitude maintains 2 browser contexts: the host browser that loaded your HTML and an embedded browser-like object (or iframe or proxy server) represented by the UIWebView instance.

Only one of those (not clear which from your discussion) has the user/pass for access to your image. You will need to call something to repeat the authentication step or transfer credentials to the other context.